# How to access JSON data in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays, json

It may seems silly question, I am little newbie here for `JSON` and trying to access the below `JSON data` in my `JS file`

```
[
    {
        "1": [
            "video1",
            "ENG"
        ]
    },
    {
        "2": [
            "video2",
            "CHI"
        ]
    }
]
```

But I am not able to access 
I have tried `console.log(data[1])` and `console.log(data[2])` but it did not work.

I need to create a new variable like this (so probably I need the `for loop` but before I use `for loop` I need to know how to access this `JSON` )

```
new_data =  "tracks: [{ 
            file: "video1", 
            label: "ENG"

       },{ 
            file: "video2", 
            label: "CHI"
        }]"
```

for little bit background how I created the `JSON`, I used below code to generate `JSON` in 
`PHP` from an `array`

This was the `PHP array` I had

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [vid] => 1 [video_name] => video1.mp4 [sub_path] => http://abc.example.com/files/eng.vtt [sub_lang] => ENG [status] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [vid] => 2 [video_name] => video2.mp4 [sub_path] => http://def.example.com/files/china.vtt [sub_lang] => CHI [status] => 1 ) )
```

Then I converted it to `JSON` and made a `ajax call` in my `JS` to get `JSON` data

```
  foreach ($querystring as $key => $value) {
           $cdn_sub_data [] = array($key+1 => array($value -> sub_path, $value -> sub_lang ));
        }

print json_encode($cdn_sub_data);
```

Help me where I am doing wrong !!! Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var data = JSON.parse(ArrayHere);
console.log(data);
data.something = "hello";
```

And back is

```
var JSON = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is wrapped in an array with one element.  You would use `data[0]["1"][0]` to get `"data1"`, for example.

You could also build the JSON you're emitting in such a way so as to prevent wrapping it in an entire array or wrapping it in an array with element `tracks` instead of using a numeric key (which should force conversion to an object).

```
array("tracks"
    => array(
        array(
            "file" => "video1",
            "label" => "ENG",
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON.parse for transform your "string from php" example:

```
var j = JSON.parse('[{"1": ["data1", "ENG"]},{ "2": ["data2","CHI"]}]'); 
    console.log(j);
```

check also this link:

[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)